# web.xml session-timeout not taken into account in spring-boot web app?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a `war` webapp that is build with `spring-boot-starter-web` and runs on a `tomcat8`.

For only one application I want to increase the session timeout. Therefore added the following file:

`/src/main/resources/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>600</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

But the TTL session timeout still remains the default 30 mins. Why?

Comment: Do you need a limit? Why not just turn it off completely? Set it to 0 for that.

Comment: It's just an example. And yet I need a definite limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard maven project, the WEB-INF folder is in src/main/webapp and not in src/main/resources. The issue can comes from this.

You check your packaged war file for the location of the web.xml file.

You can find an exemple project structure here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional

Comment: As far as I know the `server.*` properties only apply when running on an *embedded tomcat*. That's why the docs properties topic is explicit `# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION`. But I have a war file that I deploy to a standalone tomcat.

Comment: Hi, can you check that when you package your war file the web.xml file is correctly packages in WEB-INF/web.xml ? Because if it's the case it should work. In standard maven project, the WEB-INF folder is in src/main/webapp and not in src/main/resources.
You can see a standard spring-boot web project here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional

Comment: good catch! moving the file to `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` solved it! Could you rewrite your answer accordingly so I can accept it?